# How to personalize CP Content -> Edit view?

Tags: control-panel, add-on-development

I want to personalize CP Content->Edit view with custom data from each entry.

For example i want to show the value of a fieldtype.

How to procede?
I think that there isn't any hook.

The only way seems to edit:

system/expressionengine/controllers/cp/content_edit.php

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no hook for this in EE2. [Zenbu](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zenbu) is a popular addon that offers this functionality within a completely separate module.

Comment: I know Zenbu, but I want to built my custom addon, so I want to investigate which is the best way to proceed. Also I need to show in Content View data that aren't stored fieldtype.

Comment: As I say, unfortunately there is no hook for manipulating the rows/columns on the native edit entries page ([reference](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/cp/content_edit/index.html)). I'm afraid I'm not really clear what you mean by 'show in Content View data that aren't stored fieldtype'.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Zenbu, you might want to buy it and use it as your foundation and expand on their code to accomplish what you are needing to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only elegant way to personalize Content Edit is to modifying the DOM with JS.
It's possibile to add JS to CP with this hook:

**[cp_js_end](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/cp/javascript/index.html)**

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/cp/javascript/index.html